# Ubuntu 20.04.3 Problems running Firefox from terminal

Tags: command-line, 20.04, firefox

I am a fresh user of Ubuntu 20.04.3. I came across a problem with running `firefox` web browser from the terminal.

When I type 'firefox' in the terminal I get the message:

```
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.

ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.

ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.

ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
```

Firefox eventually launches, but if I close the terminal window it also shuts down my firefox.

Comment: Please edit the question to add the terminal outputs as code, instead of posting screenshots.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways to make your background process resilient to *hangup* first, you have `nohup` which instructs the [signal](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/5e36c0ce078a65c7dac6ac5ebdfb0cf096856427/src/nohup.c#L208) function to ignore `SIGHUP` before replacing itself with the new process (execvp). However, for applications that re-implements signal handling, this is not possible.

Next, the `setsid` command works much the same way, but instead of manipulating the signal, [setsid()](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/135dd1dd14712a3a19ec723729a2943e38b1e4be/sys-utils/setsid.c#L115) is used to create a new session, this will not make your application immune, but at least it will not receive any more signal from the terminal. Now, these two commands can be combined, e.i., if SIGHUP is honored, or nohup will be redundant.

Lastly, with `disown` you can either remove your application from active jobs or mark the application using `-h` to not receive SIGHUP sent from the shell. Now, as with `setsid`, this will not make your application immune, but as long as SIGHUP is not sent directly to the process, you should be fine.

```
firefox &>/dev/null & disown
```

You may also disown a running application.

```
$ firefox
ctrl + z
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 firefox
$ bg
$ disown
```

`disown` also takes either jobspec or pid as an argument.

Comment: +1, Thanks, this is a very useful answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to close the terminal after launching the graphical software you need to use `--detach`.

Example:

```
firefox --detach
```

Comment: I do not see `--detach` on [firefox's man-page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/firefox.1.html). Do you mean `Ctrl`+`Z`, followed by `bg` ?

Comment: Do you know the difference between using `firefox --detach &` and `nohup firefox &` (except that nohup will save terminal output to `nohup.out`)?

Comment: @N0rbert, you are right, but it works anyway.

Comment: @N0rbert This is the same parameter used by the Firefox ESR based TOR Bundle browser, that why it works and is simple enough for the OP to use.

Comment: @ChanganAuto after using firefox --detach, on an attempt to close terminal, it still closes the web browser

Comment: @kowczarek Simply put that's not possible. Either you typed something wrong or maybe your trying to run it as root, something you should never do.

Comment: @kowczarek, `--detach` works for me, but something must be different between our systems. Anyway, please try `nohup firefox &` and let us know how that works, when you close your terminal window. - By the way, how do you close your terminal?

Comment: @sudodus I have tried 'nohup firefox &' it launches the firefox and I am able to close terminal, but when I do it likes kill my firefox session and I get this message: "Gah. Your tab just crashed. We can help! Choose Restore This Tab to reload the page."

And for your question 'how do I close terminal' I just press the X in the upper right corner, is it a bad way to do it? :(

Comment: usually, when you really want to detach a process I think `setsid` works best.

Comment: @kowczarek, This is strange. I tested in my main computer with 18.04.x LTS, where it works. Now I tested in a test system with an up to date standard Ubuntu 20.04.3, and I get the same as you. It ***should*** be OK to close the terminal window with the x button :-( But when I closed the terminal by typing `exit` (from bash in the terminal window), firefox survived without complaint :-)

Comment: See [this link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/G4wNMBRYMY/) to the Ubuntu pastebin with the output to the Firefox tab and to `nohup.out`, when exiting from `gnome-terminal' in Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

Comment: You are right @bac0n, `setsid firefox &` works. Firefox survives when exiting from `gnome-terminal' in Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (also when pressing the x button). Can you explain the difference? I suggest that you write an answer (and I promise to upvote it).

Comment: maybe `setsid -f firefox` works.

Answer (score 1):

A couple notes regarding launching firefox in background

1. Error `ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.` only happens when you do not have any firefox windows launched. If you have at least one window - you may use syntax

> firefox -new-window https://sample.com/url

2. Instead of disown and detaching you may use another trick - launch new terminal window. It will give you ability to see logs. For example, I launch symfony backend and react front end using simple bash command

> gnome-terminal --title="Backend" -- bash -c 'cd
> /home/zhil/projects/.../backend ; symfony serve --no-tls'
>
> sleep 3
>
> gnome-terminal --title="Firefox" -- bash -c 'firefox -new-window http://localhost:8000/...'
>
> sleep 3
>
> gnome-terminal --title="Frontent" -- bash -c 'cd /home/zhil/projects/.../frontend ; npm start'
>
> firefox -new-window http://localhost:3000